# Usar una variable dentro como parámetro dentro de una función en PHP

Tags: php, funciones, variables

Necesito incrementar cíclicamente el valor de un parámetro dentro de una función, en este caso `substr`, para extraer los caracteres de una frase, uno por otro, para después hacer otro proceso. He probado poniendo una variable que se va incrementando mediante un `while`. Lo he probado declarando la variable como también poniéndolo como valor dentro de la función, pero no me ha dado resultado. Cuando llamo a la variable con un `echo`, esta sí se incrementa, pero la función sigue arrojando el resultado como si tomara solamente el primer valor que se le dio a la variable.

```
<?php
function trad(**$i**)
    {
        //**$i=0**;
        $f="hola";
        $p=substr("hola",**$i**,1);
        $v=strlen($f);
            while($i < $v) 
            {
            echo $p; 
            $i++;   
            }
    }
    trad(0);
?>
// resultado de esta funcion es: hhhh en vez de hola
```

Comment: Cual es el objetivo..resultado deseado?

Comment: @aldanux Por lo que indica en su último comentario dentro de su código el resultado tendría que ser `hola` en vez de `hhh` que es el que le está dando ahora.

Answer (score 2):

Te indico dos opciones: una que considero más optima (`Opción 1`, sin pasarle parámetro a la función) y otra que sigue tu esquema (`Opción 2`, pasándole parámetro a tu función).

**Opción 1:**

Lo primero, no se porque usas `**` antes y después de la variable. Tu problema no me queda del todo claro pero por lo que puedo deducir, lo que quieres hacer es dividir el String y después mostrarlo por pantalla todo junto de nuevo.

Lo que puedes hacer es dividir cada uno de los caracteres del String y guardarlos en un array. Una vez hecho esto, recorrer cada uno de los elementos del array para imprimirlos con un `foreach`:

```
<?php
function trad()
    {
        $f="hola";
        $arr1 = str_split($f);

        foreach ($arr1 as $valor){
            echo $valor;
        }
    }
    trad();
?>
```

El código anterior devolvería:

```
hola
```

**Opción 2:**

En caso de que quieras seguir con el modelo de tu ejemplo deberías de volver a hacer el `substr` de nuevo dentro del bucle. Tal que así:

```
<?php
function trad($i)
    {

    $f="hola";
    $v=strlen($f);

    while($i < $v) 
    {
        $p=substr($f,$i,1);
        echo $p;
        $i++;   
    }
}
trad(0);
```

?>

Lo que te devolvería:

```
hola
```

Comment: no entiendo el segundo código... no tiene mucho sentido... el `echo` y 2 veces la variable `$p`

Comment: @aldanux En realidad en el segundo ejemplo he seguido totalmente su esquema. Como el ha usado la primera variable antes del bucle, la he usado yo también simplemente por inercia. ¿Que podría ser más eficiente  y con menos código mi segunda opción? Sí, pero por eso he añadido una opción 1 la cual me resulta mucho más limpia y eficaz. En la segunda opción he seguido su esquema totalmente para que pueda darse cuenta de los errores que ha cometido en su código y pueda comparar.

Comment: @aldanux Finalmente, he dejado la opción 2 un poco más limpia. Me estaba dando remordimientos dejarla así.

Comment: jajaja tampoco era pa tanto hombre. Pero si ya esta mucho mejor! Pero sigo sin entender el objetivo de este señor (OP) :/

Comment: @aldanux Lo sé pero más vale enseñar bien, que para enseñar mal mejor no enseñar :D. Yo tampoco lo tengo demasiado claro la verdad. No tiene sentido dividir un string para mostrarlo todo junto aunque es lo único que he podido interpretar de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

No se si acertare esta vez, porque aún no se realmente tu objetivo, pero te dejo una función donde podrías jugar un poco con el *string*, tal como creo que lo estás deseando:

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6bfb641fbad816f1eeb2eaed2dc573ad6d5d8899)**

```
function trad($string, $i, $t) {

    $p = '';

    for ($i; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {

        $p .= substr($string, $i, $t);
    }

     echo $p;
}

trad('hola', 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

La función `refactorizada` *(aplicando cambios)* , No es necesario trabajar con una cadena en tu función [substr](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php) si no emplear directamente la variable. lo mismo que haces con [strlen](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php)

```
<?php 
  function trad($i)
   {
      $f="hola";
      while($i < strlen($f)) 
      {
       echo substr($f,$i++,1);
      }
    }
  trad(0); 
 ?>
```

Aunque la recomendación sería que la cadena también la recibas por `parámetro` y tu función sea algo más global y `completa`

```
 <?php 
  function trad($i,$f)
  {
    while($i < strlen($f)) 
     {
      echo substr($f,$i++,1);
    }
  }
 trad(0,"CualqierCadena"); 
 ?>
```